# Flattening an inner array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to make an area that outputs the following: `[@month, @monthly_count]` so that the complete output looks like this:  `[["January", 0], ["February", 0], ["March", 0], ["April", 2], ["May", 3], ["June", 19], ["July", 0], ["August", 0], ["September", 0], ["October", 0], ["November", 0], ["December", 0]]`

My code is:

```
@months = [["January"],["February"],["March"],["April"],["May"],["June"],["July"],["August"],["September"],["October"],["November"],["December"]]
@monthly_count = [[0], [0], [0], [2], [3], [19], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]] 
@monthly_activity_count = Array.new(12){Array.new}
          i = 0
    12.times do |i|
      @monthly_activity_count[i] << @months[i]
      @monthly_activity_count[i] << @monthly_count[i]
      @monthly_activity_count[i].flatten
      i += 1
    end
```

But it outputs:

```
[[["January"], [0]], [["February"], [0]], [["March"], [0]], [["April"], [2]], [["May"], [3]], [["June"], [19]], [["July"], [0]], [["August"], [0]], [["September"], [0]], [["October"], [0]], [["November"], [0]], [["December"], [0]]]
```

I tried to use `array.flatten` within the iterator to flatten each individual array while keeping the array bounds around each month, but this didn't work. How can I make the array correctly?

Comment: Is there more context for your code? What are `@monthly_activity_count` and `@months` set to before this portion of code?

Comment: @BenCoppock edited above with the proper context, thanks for the suggestions

Comment: What is `@monthly_count`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the context. Why is `@months` an array of arrays? Why not just an array of month names?

Comment: @sawa `@monthly_count` is an array of integers, I added it above.  My expected output is in the first line.

Comment: @BenCoppock I did that because it was in line with the other arrays I had done, probably a mistake.

Comment: @VirgeAssault: `@monthly_count` is not an array of integers, it is an array of arrays, where each of the inner arrays contains exactly one integer. Likewise, `@months` is an array of arrays, where each of the inner arrays contains exactly one string. If `@monthly_count` were an array of integers and `@months` were an array of strings, you wouldn't need to flatten the result in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by doing `flatten!` in your code,

```
12.times do |i|
    @monthly_activity_count[i] << @months[i]
    @monthly_activity_count[i] << @monthly_count[i]
    @monthly_activity_count[i].flatten!
    i += 1
  end
```

Comment: This worked! Is using the `!` symbol frowned upon here at all? I'm hesitant bc I was taught to not use it much in CSS, not sure if its the same way of "forcing" it

Comment: Yes its forcing but that doesn't mean you never have to use it. Basically it assigns value of flatten back to its calling instance. +1

Answer (score 0):

`flatten(level)` works for you.

```
[[["January"], [0]], [["February"], [0]], [["March"], [0]], [["April"], [2]], [["May"], [3]], [["June"], [19]], [["July"], [0]], [["August"], [0]], [["September"], [0]], [["October"], [0]], [["November"], [0]], [["December"], [0]]].flatten(2)
```

For more information   http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten

Comment: This didn't change anything with placed in the iterator like `@monthly_count[i].flatten(2)`, and gave me the wrong output `["January", 0, "February", 0, "March", 0, "April", 2, "May", 3, "June", 19, "July", 0, "August", 0, "September", 0, "October", 0, "November", 0, "December", 0]` when I did `@monthly_count.flatten(2)` outside the iterator.  I'll adjust for dif levels outside, but I really want something inside the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```
@monthly_activity_count = @months.flatten.zip(@monthly_count.flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're attempting to get at, you can probably start with a slightly simpler setup:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

From there, you can use either of the following lines to produce the desired array (they're exactly equivalent):

```
months.map.with_index { |month, index| [month, index] }
months.collect.with_index { |month, index| [month, index] }
```

Both of those lines will iterate over your months array, passing the month name and its index into the block. The code block (the portion surrounded by `{` and `}` returns an array containing just the month name and index — and all of those little arrays are grouped into a containing array because you're using `map` (or `collect`).

However, I can't quite imagine why you'd need such a structure. If you know the index of the month you want, you can get its name like so:

```
months[index]
```

If you know the month name and want to know its index, you can find out like so:

```
month_name = "March"
index = months.index { |month| month == month_name }
```

The `index` in `months.index` will iterate over all the months, passing each one into the code block. It expects you to supply a code block that will return `true` when you've located the object you want the index of. So the code block (`month == month_name`) is setup to match the name of the month passed in with the name stored in your `month_name` variable. See [this article](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) for more info on Ruby code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
# only using some of the array to make the example easier to read
@months = [["January"],["February"],["March"],["April"],["May"]]
@monthly_count = [[0], [0], [0], [2], [3]] 


## First Method

zipped = @months.zip(@monthly_count)
=> [[["January"], [0]], [["February"], [0]], [["March"], [0]], [["April"], [2]], [["May"], [3]]]

@monthly_activity_count = zipped.each { |pair| pair.flatten! }
=> [["January", 0], ["February", 0], ["March", 0], ["April", 2], ["May", 3]]

# could also do it as a one liner
@months.zip(@monthly_count).each { |pair| pair.flatten! }
# the flatten! in the line above is not bad, just a warning to help you understand 
# the result. The difference between `flatten` and `flatten!` is that `flatten`
# will create a new array to hold the result, whereas `flatten!` will 
# modify the array you call it on.


## Second Method

@months.flatten.zip(@monthly_count.flatten)
=> [["January", 0], ["February", 0], ["March", 0], ["April", 2], ["May", 3]]


## Ideal Method

# if you can get your months and monthly_count data as simple arrays, eg ["January", 
# "February", ...] then you can remove the flattens in the previous line, giving:
@months.zip(@monthly_count)
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip for the docs of the `zip` method.

See http://dablog.rubypal.com/2007/8/15/bang-methods-or-danger-will-rubyist for an explanation of ! (bang) methods in ruby.